# explain output of this matlab for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Can someone explain how this loop results in an output that looks like this?
I just don't understand how the iterations are progressing.

`for` loop:

```
for ii = 1:5
    fprintf('%4d', ii*[1:ii])
    fprintf('\n')
end
```

Output:

```
1  
2  4  
3  6  9    
4  8  12  16  
5  10 15  20  25
```

Comment: Well in the first iteration, `ii` is 1, so you are doing `1*[1:1]` which is `1*1=1`. In the second iteration, `ii=2`, so `2*[1:2]=2*[1 2]=[2 4]`, then `ii=3` so `3*[1:3]=3*[1 2 3]=[3 6 9]` etc. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: David, yes! Thank you.  
For some reason, I thought the 1 in the brackets was a constant whose function was to reference individual elements.
I just started programming so it makes sense that such a silly mistake would cause so much confusion.  I suppose I was blind to the semicolon and had mistaken it for a comma. Thanks again!